# How can i fix ActiveAdmin 'Edit' action route that doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've just created the active admin dashboard and everything seemed to work but when creating a new admin user I've received an URLGeneration error, though the user is created on going back to the dashboard. The same error occurs when I try to 'View' the user I've just created or any user including the default admin user. The same goes as I click to the 'Id' of the admin users.

(The Error)

```
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::AdminUsers#show

showing .../bundler/gems/activeadmin-b9f189ff671a/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb where line #2 raised:

 No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/admin_users", :id=>#<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil, image: nil>}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

(config/routes.rb)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

(models/admin_user.rb)

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
 devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Admin file:

(admin/admin_users.rb)

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

(admin/dashboard.rb)

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div class: "blank_slate_container", id: "dashboard_default_message" do
      span class: "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end

  end # content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
No route matches {
 :action=>"edit", 
 :controller=>"admin/admin_users", 
 :id=>#<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil, image: nil>
}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

My read on the above is that the `edit` route is expecting an ID but is instead getting a bad value. Combining that with this

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::AdminUsers#show`

and with your description of what you did leads me to believe that there's a problem with the way `edit` links are being generated within the `show` view.

Can you update your question to include the ActiveAdmin 'show' view? It would also be helpful to include your ActiveAdmin resource file (should be in `app/admin`).

Comment: Hi Matt, I believe that Active Admin auto-generates the views for such functionality, or am I wrong? I'm just getting started with Ruby, any clarification would be great

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that poorly. Yes, the view itself is generated (using the resource file). What I meant to ask was if you could share the rendered HTML produced by the view; my thought was to look at the HTML for the link to see if anything was malformed.

Comment: I checked it out, it's the same as the one ActiveAdmin has on github